# Finding a truth value from a given statement.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $Q(x,y)$ be the statement $"x+2=3y"$, what are the truth values of

$\forall x\exists yQ(x,y)$,

$ \exists x \forall y(x,y)$,

and $ \forall x \forall yQ(x,y) $?

I know how to do it if $Q(x)$ be the statement $"x+2=3x"$. For example:

For $\forall xQ(x)$ be false and $\exists xQ(x)$ be true as $x+2=3x$ is true if and only if $x=1$, we see that $Q(x)$ is true if and only if $x=1$.

But when $Q(x,y)$, I not quite sure how to get the truth values. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a $y$ in the equation?  Also, what are the universal sets for $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Yes, there is. Sorry, I miss typed it. I have made the correction now.

Comment: One thing you can try is substituting various values for $x,y$ to get a feel for the truth value:  For  example $Q(4,2):   \  4+2=3(2),$  which is true.  On the other hand,  $Q(4,3):   \ \ 4 + 2 = 3(3)$ is false since $6 \neq 9.$    Thus there are some values of $(x,y)$ for the statement is false.

Comment: I think for the second statement you mean $\exists x \forall y Q(x,y)$.  Also, are we saying $\forall y \in \Bbb R$ and $\forall x \in \Bbb R$?

Comment: To study the first statement $(\forall x)(\exists y)  Q(x,y)$,  can you answer the following question:  Given any $x\in \mathbb{R},$  can a I find specific $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x+2=3y.$    It appears you can:  $y=\frac{1}{3}(x+2)$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It is making a whole lot sense now.

Answer (score 0):

What is the universal set? If the universal set is $R$, then the first one is TRUE. The second and the third are false. For the first one, given any x in R, take y as $\frac{1}{3}(x+2)$.   For the second one, given x=0, then y=1 gives a contradiction. The same counter example works for the third one.

Comment: To answer the second question, suppose there is such an x. Then x=3y-2 for all y. in particular, for y=0 and y=1. Thus x=-2 and x=1. i.e -2=1---a contradiction. For the third, x=0, y=1 shows that the proposition is not true.

Comment: Prove the first by contradiction. Assume that the first statement is false. Then $\exists x\forall y$, $x+2\neq 3y$.   We may assume without loss of generality that $x+2>3y$ for all reals. In particular, for $y=\frac{1}{3}(x+2)$ we obtain that $x+2>(3y=x+2)$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Appreciate your time and help. It was really helpful.